# jQuery multi select bug

Tags: jquery

Is it a bug?
This select works:

```
<select id="select_advsels" name="pixel_advsels" multiple>
<option>All</option><option>Mobvista (TS-126)</option>
</select>

jQuery('#select_advsels').val(['Mobvista (TS-126)']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w2xtU/

When two words in OPTION are separated by more than one space, jQuery fails to select:

```
<select id="select_advsels" name="pixel_advsels" multiple>
<option>All</option><option>Mobvista  (TS-126)</option>
</select>

jQuery('#select_advsels').val(['Mobvista  (TS-126)']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3FrR7/2/

Comment: it is not jQuery - html replaces the continues spaces with a single one see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gaErU/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Post it!

Comment: This is how it should work.

Comment: @tymeJV I didn't post it because I can't find a spec to support it

Answer (score 4):

While html is rendered, it replaces the continues spaces with a single one :

```
jQuery('#select_advsels option').each(function(){
    console.log(this.value.replace(' ', '-'));
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gaErU)

Refer [this](http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/whitespace.html)

> HTML treats whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, and newlines)
>   differently from ordinary characters. In general, a single whitespace
>   character--including newlines--or a sequence of whitespace characters
>   are treated as a single space and leading/trailing whitespace is
>   eliminated. This is known as 'collapsing whitespace'. Therefore the
>   following two paragraphs are treated as if they were identical

Answer (score 1):

As has already been explained, the browser collapses multiple continuous whitespace characters down to a single space. If you absolutely need to preserve the double spaces then use explicit `value` attributes when declaring your `<option>` tags:

```
<option value="Mobvista  (TS-126)">Mobvista  (TS-126)</option>
```

The value displayed to the user will only have a single space, but the value sent when the form is submitted or matched when using JavaScript will retain the multiple spaces.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FrR7/7/)